# How to repaint automatically after event like button click?

Tags: java, swing

After I click a button I want some of the components of the `JPanel` to be removed and some new ones to be created.

I'm able to remove and add the new ones, but the `JPanel` doesn't repaint itself. Only after I do something manually, like change the frame size, the frame "refreshes" and I get what I want.

Here's the relevant part of the code, in this example it initiates the components by the given date:

```
private ClassName() {
    date = Date.getToday();
    init(date.toString());
}

private void lastDayActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    this.removeAll();
    date = date.getYesterday();
    init(date.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want the component to re-layout and repaint after the button has been pushed and after it modifies the state of your GUI, then directly call within your ActionListener's code:

```
private void lastDayActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    this.removeAll();
    date = date.getYesterday();
    init(date.toString());
    revalidate();  // re-lays out child components
    repaint();    // repaints the component
}
```

But, it really sounds like you really want to use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to swap views for you since this is exactly what this class was created for.